# How do I search for keywords in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, keyword, keyword-search

I have a search form which works very well but I want to add keyword functionality to it. I'm not sure how. The search conditions look like this:

```
def search
conditions = {}
conditions[:targ_lang] = params[:targ_lang] unless params[:targ_lang].blank?
conditions[:inst_lang] = params[:inst_lang] unless params[:inst_lang].blank?
conditions[:start_level] = params[:start_level] unless params[:start_level].blank?
conditions[:end_level] = params[:end_level] unless params[:end_level].blank?
conditions[:skill] = params[:skill] unless params[:skill].blank?
conditions[:subject] = params[:subject] unless params[:subject].blank?
conditions[:inst_name] = params[:inst_name] unless params[:inst_name].blank?
conditions[:creator] = params[:creator] unless params[:creator].blank?
#conditions = Material.where("keywords like ?", "%#{keywords}") unless params[:keywords].blank?  
@results = Material.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
end
```

I've commented out the keyword line because it doesn't work at the moment. Obviously it's different to the others because we don't want to find an exact match, we want a single match from several possible keywords.

Can anyone help? Rookie question I know but I've been working on it for a while.

Comment: might want to invest some time checking acts_as_taggable_on gem

Comment: this search functionality looks quite complex. i would like to point out that it might make sense to have a look at a fulltext search index or fulltext search funtionality like its in postgres.